# discord.js getting the name of the user that used the bot command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I need to get the name of the user that posted the content. Everything I have tried returns the ID. I have tried things like msg.author, and others.

Edit: horrible title name smh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `message.author.tag` to return the username like `username#1234` or `message.author.username` to get the username without the discriminator `username`

[Source](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)

Comment: It was no problem!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`msg.author.username`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=username)?